# How would I get the dice to keep rerolling and printing until it hits "7" or the "point"

Tags: java

I am trying to build a craps game in which the computer automatically rolls a pair of dice and if the roll is a 7 or 11 the user win. However if the user rolls a 2, 3, or 12 they automatically lose.

Furthermore, if the user rolls any other number (4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10) that is their "point" and they are to try to roll that point again. (unless they roll a 7 then they lose.) I am trying to get my while loop to continue rolling if the computer rolls a number other than 7 or the "point"

Unfortunately, my loop is not working and it does not continue to re-roll.

Thanks in advance, and this is my code:

this is what i have now:

```
public class CrapsPractice{
    public static void main(String[]args){   

        int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int roll = (d1 + d2);
        int point = roll; 

        if (roll == 7 || roll == 11) 
        {
            System.out.println("You rolled a" + roll); 
            System.out.println("Congrats! You've immediately won!");
            return; //terminate the main function
        }

        else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
        {
            System.out.println("you rolled a " + roll);
            System.out.println("You lose!");
            return; //terminate the main function
        }

        //do-while loop: execute and then check for condition
        //and then if condition holds, execute a second time and so on
        do {
            int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            roll = d3 + d4;

            System.out.println("your point is" + point);

        } while(roll != 7 && roll != point );
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like in your print statement you want to print `roll`, not `point`. Either that or reassign `point`. (I'm not all that clear on the rules of craps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me but try these printouts instead to get a better idea of what is happening:

```
//do-while loop: execute and then check for condition
//and then if condition holds, execute a second time and so on
do {
    int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    roll = d3 + d4;

    System.out.println("your roll is " + roll + " and point is " + point);

} while(roll != 7 && roll != point );

if (roll == 7) 
    System.out.println("you lose");
else
    System.out.println("you win");
```

Output:

```
your roll is 6 and point is 9
your roll is 4 and point is 9
your roll is 3 and point is 9
your roll is 8 and point is 9
your roll is 8 and point is 9
your roll is 6 and point is 9
your roll is 9 and point is 9
you win
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```